# how to setup a webhosting site?

Tags: php, web-hosting

I have purchased a cPanel/WHM web hosting reseller account and I want to set up a site for people to set up a hosting accounts. I also would like to have a domain name registration system on the site, so people can register the domain name they would like to host with me. How can I do this? Are there any ready-made scripts available or should I create my own script using the WHM API?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I would highly recommend going for [WHMCS](http://www.whmcs.com/). Ok it is a little pricey but it integrates so tightly with WHM and has so many features you won't need anything else.

It provides a complete customer management system, with module creation, invoicing, online payments, knowledgebase, support ticket system and a domain name registration system allowing customers to purchase a domain name and package and have it set up automatically for them hands free.

It also integrates with all the big name domain resellers. I just sit and let it fire off the reminder emails and watch the customers pay and domains/hosting packages renew.

There is a free trial and I suggest giving it a go. It has completely changed the way I run my business (I was on Helm before and had to invoice manually) and I love it.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the domain registrar. For this, you'd be looking at setting up an ecommerce site (unless you want to give away domain names for free), then look at this: http://www.icann.org/en/registrars/accreditation-process.htm (tl;dr: costs $2500 and you have to fill out a load of paperwork)

My suggestion would be to offer name servers for people to switch to (usually if you've bought a reseller account your hosting company will provide this), or you could offer to buy it for people and then invoice (or the other way around).

I did what you wanted for a while, but I found it much easier to set up recurring Paypal payments (insert chosen payment provider) and then just set it up by hand. It only took about 5 or 10 mins per account.

Comment: "...costs $2500 and ..." - Some domain registrars offer reseller accounts, in the same way hosting providers offer reseller accounts for hosting. Some webhosts are both and offer reseller accounts for both. So you don't necessarily need to become a domain registrar in order to resell domains. Just saying.

Comment: True. That slipped my mind